# how to remove Error : "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'."

Tags: webpack, android-manifest, nativescript, manifest

in nativescript App i have this Error , I did not find a solution.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
  >       is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
  >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:17:2-38:16 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Unable to apply changes on device: 5HR6R19222047269. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.

Comment: What is the version of {NS} and on which platform you are facing this issue?

Comment: It's related to AndroidX and dependencies. http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=942 this blog post outlines a couple approaches to fix until NS 6 which will be AndroidX by default.

Answer (score 0):

add this to `app.gradle`

```
dependencies {
 configurations.all {
      exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
         def requested = details.requested
         if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
           details.useVersion '17.+'
         }
         if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
             details.useVersion '16.+'
         }
         if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && requested.name != 'multidex') {
             // com.android.support major version should match buildToolsVersion
             details.useVersion '28.+'
         }           
     }
 }
}
```